# Adding annotations to a PlotChart

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I'm looking to add(and remove, dynamically) text annotations to the PlotChart.  Specifically I want to annotate plot points in the chart.  I'm currently using the CircleItemRenderer for the points.

I've found tutorials for other plot types, but they don't seem to apply to the PlotChart.

Anyone have any examples, or can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of doing this kind of thing is to add an instance of CartesianDataCanvas to the annotationElements property of your chart.  This is [documented in Livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_eventsandeffects_14.html) for Line Charts, but the principle is the same for any cartesian chart.

There's also a [brief discussion on FlexCoders](http://www.mail-archive.com/flexcoders@yahoogroups.com/msg91866.html).